# iOS ModalViewとして表示したViewControllerにNavigationControllerを追加する方法

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

ViewControllerの画面遷移時に下記コードで、NavigationControllerを追加した所NavigationControllerの灰色のNavigationBarと真っ白なViewのみが表示されてしまいTestVCのViewが表示されない状況です。

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    TestVC *VC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TestVC"];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:VC];
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

ネットで確認した所、上記方法が紹介されていたのですがうまくいきません。
対応策ご存知の方いましたらご教授お願いします。

Comment: `UINavigationController`を使わずに、`VC`をモーダル表示することはできていますか？（Objective-Cの命名規則に従って、インスタンス名は小文字で始めること（例：`vc`）をお勧めします。）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];`を実装していなかったため自分で実装したnavigationbarがnavigationController付属のbarの下に隠れていたのが原因でした。

Comment: それが原因とは思えませんし、それにその`[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];`は、ご提示のコードのどこにも書かれていませんよね？

Comment: 補足します。私が表示しようとしているViewControllerのバー部分以外の実装は何も表示されていないのが初期状態では正常なものでした。NavigationBarと真っ白なviewが表示されたことで初期化に失敗したNavigationControllerが表示されてしまったのではという私の勘違いです。実際は単にNavigationBarの下に私がカスタムViewで作成したNavigationBar風のものが表示されていたのです。それは[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]を実装して私のカスタムNavigationBarが表示されたのでわかりました。